# Combine 2 lists with having common object value c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, model

I have two custom lists.

```
public class Model1
    {
        public string EmpGuid { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    }

public class Model2
        {
            public string EmpGuid { get; set; }
            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
            public DateTime Anniversary{ get; set; }

        }
```

Now I create 2 lists from these classes like so :-

```
var List1 = new List<Model1>();
var List2 = new List<Model2>();
```

In my Model classes the values for EmpGuid is unique and is the same in both lists. Now I want to create one single class with the following properties

```
public class Model3
        {
            public string EmpGuid { get; set; }
            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
            public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
           public DateTime Anniversary{ get; set; }
        }
```

Here I want to combine both the list ie. List1 and List 2 grouping them with the EmpGuid such that I have a single List of type List where I have the Birthday and anniversary for each EmpGuid.

The final output should be :-

**EDIT**

```
  List 1 - EmpGuid - abc
        EmpName - emp1
        Birthday - something

        EmpGuid - xyz
        EmpName - emp2
        Birthday - something2

List 2 - EmpGuid - abc
        EmpName - emp1
        Anniversary - somethingAnniversary

        EmpGuid - mno
        empName - emp3
        Anniversary - somethingAnniversary3

List3 - EmpGuid - abc
        EmpName - emp1
        Birthday - something
        Anniversary - somethingAnniversary

        EmpGuid - xyz
        EmpName - emp2
        Birthday - something2
        Anniversary - null


        EmpGuid - mno
        EmpName - emp3
        Birthday - null
        Anniversary - somethingAnniversary3
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: But if `EmployeeName` can also be different from which list do you want to take it?

Comment: Have you tried anything based on our solutions? We´re not doing all the work for you.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes Iam trying all the solutions everyone has helped me with here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using LINQ's `Join` method:

```
var List3 = List1.Join(List2, l1 => l1.EmpGuid, l2 => l2.EmpGuid, 
                    (l1, l2) => new Model3 {
                             EmpGuid = l1.EmpGuid,
                             EmployeeName = l1.EmployeeName,
                             BirthDate = l1.BirthDate,
                             Anniversary = l2.Anniversary}).ToList();
```

This combines the two lists by comparing the `EmpGuid`s and creates for each combination a new `Model3` instance.

One problem is that you said the `EmployeeName` can be different, so you have to decide which one you take or how you combine them.

---

Unfortunatly there is no full outer join in LINQ, so you will need to this a little more manually. One possibility is to add the missing elements after the above query like this:

```
List3.AddRange(List1.Where(l1 => List2.All(l2 => l1.EmpGuid != l2.EmpGuid)
                    .Select(l1 => new Model3 {
                         EmpGuid = l1.EmpGuid,
                         EmployeeName = l1.EmployeeName,
                         BirthDate = l1.BirthDate,
                         Anniversary = null}));
```

and the same the other way around:

```
List3.AddRange(List2.Where(l2 => List1.All(l1 => l1.EmpGuid != l2.EmpGuid)
                    .Select(l2 => new Model3 {
                         EmpGuid = l2.EmpGuid,
                         EmployeeName = l2.EmployeeName,
                         Anniversary = l2.Anniversary}));
```

This takes all elements from the one list with GUIDs that don't appear in the second list and creates the appropriate `Model3` instances. (Note that `DateTime` is a value type and cannot be null, by default it's `DateTime.MinValue`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this out. But this only gives me the values which have a common EmpGuid. I want to include others as well which are not common

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I agree the issue was a little complicated. But really appreciate your patience and time

Answer (score 2):

You will make a join on both lists, similar to SQL:

```
var result = from m1 in list1
    join m2 in list2 on m1.EmpGuid == m2.EmpGuid
    select new Model3 { EmpGuid = m1.EmpGuid, EmployeeeName = m1.EmployeeName ...};
```

However this will *allways* use the `EmployseeName` from `Model1`. If you want to select both names you can use this approach;

```
var result = from m1 in list1
    join m2 in list2 on m1.EmpGuid == m2.EmpGuid
    select new Model3 
    { 
        EmpGuid = m1.EmpGuid, 
        EmployeeeName1 = m1.EmployeeName,
        EmployeeeName2 = m2.EmployeeName,
        ...
    };
```

Also have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397941.aspx).

Comment: I normally stick with method syntax, but in this case query syntax really looks better.

Comment: @RenéVogt Feel the same

Comment: Please check my desired output in the edit . I want to take the EmpNames from the first list

Comment: Thanks for the time. Upvoting the answer for your help.